# How to handle expired refresh tokens during GraphQL request

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-graphql

I have a Vaadin view that shows `News` entries:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class NewsView extends VerticalLayout
    private final NewsService service;

    protected void onAttach(final AttachEvent attachEvent) {
        if (attachEvent.isInitialAttach()) {
            service.getNews().subscribe(result -> addNewsEntries(attachEvent.getUI(), result));
        }
    }

    private void addNewsEntries(final UI ui, final List<News> result) {
        // This takes the DTOs, creates Vaadin components for each and adds them to the page.
        ui.access(() -> result.stream().map(NewsEntry::new).forEach(this::add));
    }
}
```

The service is quite simple, it defines the GraphQL query and sends it on to the `GraphQlService`:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class NewsService {
    private final GraphQlService graphQlService;

    public Mono<List<News>> getNews() {
        final String query = """
            query NewsQuery {
                publishedNews {
                    id
                    author
                    publishingDate
                    children {
                        language
                        text
                    }
                }
            }""";

        return graphQlService.queryList(query, Map.of(), "publishedNews", News.class);
    }
}
```

Which in turn uses a Spring `HttpGraphQlClient` to send the actual POST request:

```
@Service
public class GraphQlService {
    private final HttpGraphQlClient client;

    public GraphQlService(final WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder, final ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
        final OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository, final @Value("${baseUrl}") String baseUrl) {
        final var oauth2Client = new ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(clientRegistrationRepository,
authorizedClientRepository);
        webClientBuilder.apply(oauth2Client.oauth2Configuration())
            .defaultRequest(request -> request.attributes(clientRegistrationId("custom")));
        client = HttpGraphQlClient.builder(webClientBuilder.build()).url(baseUrl).build();
    }

    @NotNull
    public <T> Mono<List<T>> queryList(final String query, final Map<String, Object> arguments, final String jsonPath, final Class<T> typeRef) {
        return client.document(query).variables(arguments).retrieve(jsonPath).toEntityList(typeRef);
    }
}
```

Users are authenticated via Spring Web Security and our Spring OAuth2 Authentication Server. This creates a `SecurityContext`, which is used to handle view access. The backend GraphQL service is implemented as a resource server and uses the granted access token for authentication. This works well, even requesting new access tokens works out of the box.
The problem starts, when the refresh token expires. In that case, the default error handler removes the stored authentication from the `OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository`, causing an `OAuth2AuthorizationException`, which gets wrapped in a `GraphQlTransportException`. Any subsequent request will cause a `ClientAuthorizationRequiredException` (again wrapped in a `GraphQlTransportException`). But the Spring `SecurityContext` handling the normal application security is NOT cleared. So views remain accessible, but no data can be loaded. To fix this issue a user has to log out and back in again, getting a new refresh token.

I tried a custom `RemoveAuthorizedClientOAuth2AuthorizationFailureHandler` which manually cleared the `SecurityContext`, but this did not help. I also tried manually unwrapping the exception, but the `OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter` still did not pick up on it (and the default implementation should already check the base cause anyway...).

Ideally, the user would be automatically logged out once their refresh token expires. This forces them to login again, netting them a new refresh token.